# Spectral norm of concatenation of two matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, normed-spaces

Let $A \in R^{n*p}$ and $B \in R^{n*d}$ such that both have spectral norm(largest singular value) equal to 1. Now if I concatenate the columns of $A$ and $B$ to construct $M=[A|B]$, then what can we say about the spectral norm of $M$. I am able to bound it by 2 but can we say something stronger(equal to or better upper bound)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\pmatrix{A&B}\pmatrix{A&B}^T = AA^T + BB^T
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\|\pmatrix{A&B}\|^2 = \lambda_{max}(AA^T + BB^T) \leq 
\lambda_{max}(AA^T) + \lambda_{max}(BB^T) = \|A\|^2 + \|B\|^2 = 2
$$
Thus, we have $\|\pmatrix{A&B}\| \leq \sqrt{2}$, which is the best upper bound we can get.

---

Equivalently:
$$
\| \pmatrix{A & B}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}\| = \|Ax_1 + Bx_2\| \leq \|A\|\|x_1\| + \|B\|\|x_2\| = \|x_1\| + \|x_2\|
$$
thus, we want to maximize $\|x_1\| + \|x_2\|$ under the constraint that $\|(x_1,x_2)\| = 1$, which is to say that $\|x_1\|^2 + \|x_2\|^2 = 1$.  This maximum is attained when $\|x_1\| = \|x_2\| = \sqrt{2}/2$.

Comment: I think in the first part you meant $[A | B] [A | B]^T$.

Answer (score 0):

$2$ is the optimum bound, since you can take $n=p=d=1$ and $A=B=1$. Then, in the $\infty$ norm, $\|M\|_\infty = 2$.

Comment: By operator norm, I meant norm corresponding to vector 2 norm (largest singular value or spectral norm).  For n=p=d=1, it will be sqrt(2).

Comment: @user1131274 Well, then you should really edit your question. Because "operator norm" is not the same as "$2$-norm".